# how to compile Rust code that its functions can be called through Java

Tags: java, function, rust, hyperlink, export

here is my rust code

```
#[no_mangle]
 pub extern "C" fn get_name(){
    println!("subham shaw");
}
```

and here is my java code

```
// ExampleJNI.java

public class RustTest {
    static {
       
        // Load the Rust library
        System.load("E:/Rust_pro/android_test/target/debug/sample.dll"); 
    }

    // Native method declarations
    public native void get_name();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RustTest example = new RustTest();

        example.get_name();
        
       
    }
}
```

here is my cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "android_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
jni = "0.21.1"

[lib]
name = "sample"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

i tried this code but its not working , java throwing error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void RustTest.get_name()'
        at RustTest.get_name(Native Method)
        at RustTest.main(RustTest.java:16)
```

how to solve this problem

i tried to export rust function so that it can be load using java

Answer (score 2):

When doing JNI it is useful to run the following command on your Java file:

```
javac -h . RustTest.java
```

This will create a `RustTest.h` file with the C interface to your native class, the one you have to implement in Rust: let the compiler think for you.

Now, in this file you will see the relevant declaration that you have to comply, but in Rust instead of C:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RustTest_get_1name
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

The first thing to note is the name: the function is not just `get_name` but the concatenation of `Java_` + *package_name* + *class_name* + *function_name*.

In your particular case, *package_name* does not apply, and *function_name*. I'm not sure what happens with that `1`, I think that `get_` is a reserver prefix for properties or something...

Now the Rust code, you forgot also the function arguments:

- `_env`: represents the JVM.
- `_obj`: is the `this` object.

And don't forget that Java functions should be declared as `"system"`, not `"C"`!

```
use jni::JNIEnv;
use jni::objects::JObject;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "system" fn Java_RustTest_get_1name(_env: JNIEnv, _obj: JObject){
    println!("subham shaw");
}
```

And it should work now.